# How to start gunicorn via Django manage.py after server reboot

Tags: django, ubuntu, gunicorn

I am starting gunicon by calling `python manage.py run_gunicorn` (inside a virtualenv).

How can I achieve to restart gunicorn after my Ubuntu 12.04 server rebooted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I'm on Ubuntu and like to work with tools already included in the distro I used **Upstart** to start gunicorn after booting the machine.

I put the following code into `/etc/init/django_sf_flavour.conf` :

```
description "Run Custom Script"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn
respawn limit 10 5
exec /home/USER/bin/start_gunicorn.sh
```

Which executes this file (`/home/USER/bin/start_gunicorn.sh`) after booting:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cd MY_PROJ_ROOT
source venv/bin/activate
test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR
exec python MY_PROJ_PATH/manage.py run_gunicorn
```

Comment: "start: Job failed to start" ,, 
 
upstart can't run django_sf_flavour.conf in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: after some test, I find that the problem is start_gunicorn.sh doesn't have right permission :(, so with this command "chmod 775 start_gunicorn.sh", it's work like charm :) , thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use supervisor to launch your app on startup and restart on crashes.

Install supervisor and create a config file  `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/your_app.conf` with content like this:

```
[program:your_app]
directory=/path/to/app/working/dir
command=/path/to/virtualenv_dir/bin/python /path/to/manage_py/manage.py run_gunicorn
user=your_app_user
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Answer (score 0):

this is based on @j7nn7k answer but with a bit changes

1 - create a .conf file in /etc/init dir to run with upstart

```
cd /etc/init
nano django_sf_flavour.conf
```

2 - put below lines in django_sf_flavour file and save it.

```
description "Run Custom Script"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn
respawn limit 10 5
exec /home/start_gunicorn.sh
```

3 - create start_gunicorn.sh file in  home dir with following lines

```
cd /home
nano start_gunicorn.sh
```

4 - put these code in it and save it.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cd mysite
source myenv/bin/activate
test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR
exec gunicorn —bind 0.0.0.0:80 mysite.wsgi:application
```

5 - set runable permission to start_gunicorn.sh

```
cd /home
chmod 775 start_gunicorn.sh
```

** extra **

check syntax django_sf_flavour.conf with this command

```
init-checkconf /etc/init/django_sf_flavour.conf
```

and answer should be like this:

```
File /etc/init/django_sf_flavour.conf: syntax ok
```

you can see problems in upstart log file if needed:

```
cat /var/log/upstart/django_sf_flavour.log
```

test your django_sf_flavour.conf file like this without reboot

```
service django_sf_flavour start
```

test your bash file "start_gunicorn.sh" like this

```
cd /home 
bash start_gunicorn.sh
```

check state of django_sf_flavour

```
initctl list | grep django_sf_flavour
```